# django mysql not working on pythonanywhere

Tags: mysql, django, pythonanywhere

I have tried 3 ways to access the database:

1. [WORKS] from bash shell: `~$ mysql -u <username> -h mysql.server -p '<username>$<db_name>'`
2. [WORKS] `~$ python manage.py syncdb`
3. [DOES NOT WORK]

   - Syncdb
   - Reload app
   - Go to url

Error:

`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user '<username>'@'ip-10-186-190-7.ec2.internal' (using password: NO)")`

Settings:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': '<username>$<db_name>',
    'USER': '<username>',
    'PASSWORD': <password>,
    'HOST': 'mysql.server',
    'PORT': '3306',
  }
}
```

Pythonanywhere's wsgi module is loading the correct settings script. The database password has been set and checked in the 'Databases' tab.

I am using Django 1.7, Python 3.4, mysqlclient 1.3.4, inside a virtualenv.

Thanks for your help.

[Edit]:

The first error is actually:

`AttributeError: 'SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'`

I don't know if this is meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was the lack of database connection, and not related specifically to the session backend. I was providing the password for the database though an os.environ variable. This has to be set in the python anywhere wsgi script:

```
os.environ['DB_PWD'] = '<password>'
```

All fixed.

Comment: Haha. Yes. Thanks for spotting that. My mac thinks it knows best.

Comment: Thanks @arkaeologic for the tip on how to setup wsgi file. In my settings.py I'm grabbing all my database info from env. variables like so: ```DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': environ['DB_NAME'],
        'USER': environ['DB_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': environ['DB_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': environ['DB_HOST'],
        'PORT': '',
    }
}```

Comment: [This instructions](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/environment-variables-for-web-apps/) also helped me